# sed: urecognized option -- i

Tags: windows-7, sed

I'm using Window 7.

`sed -V`

gives me

`GNU sed version 3.02`

I have a text file with:

`foo bar`

In command line if I write:

`sed s/foo/tofu/ test.txt`

I get printed on stdout;

`tofu bar`

However, I want to edit this file inplace, so using the `-i` option:

`sed -i s/foo/tofu/ test.txt`

gives me `sed: invalid option -- i`

What am I missing?

Comment: Since it's probably a rare Windows 7 user who uses sed, I'm not sure how much help you'll get. It works fine on linux.

Comment: @ooga Thanks. For now this solution works for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20999154/1068446

Comment: Perhaps you should download a later version. I'm using GNU sed 4.2.1 from 2009. It objects to `sed -V` and wants `sed --version`. Your `sed -i` line worked using that version for me.

Answer (score 1):

While I can't guarantee this will work because I'm not running it on Windows 7 but have you considered using redirection and then swapping?
Meaning something like this:
`sed s/foo/tofu/ test.txt > tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt test.txt`
While this is a very dirty way of doing things I think it might work. You can also try doing
`sed s/foo/tofu/ test.txt > test.txt`
but I feel that might lead to some errors because you're reading and writing on the same file.

Comment: `sed s/// test > test` cannot work: the shell will process the redirection **first** and the file will get truncated to 0 bytes. Then, when sed starts, its reading from an **empty file**.

Answer (score 0):

It's the sed version. Try the one found here:
http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/UnxUpdates.zip